# Why the progressBar never reaches 100%?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

What i wanted to do is that if i check if counter == 10 then the progressBar will jump by 10's untill 100.
If i will make if counter == 20 then the progressBar should jump by 20's untill 100.

```
private void NewsUpdate()
        {
            counter += 1;
            progressBar1.Value = (int)Math.Round((counter / 10f) * 100);
            label9.Text = counter.ToString();
            label9.Visible = true;
            if (counter == 10)
            {
                Extractions();
                counter = 0;
                progressBar1.Value = 0;
            }  
        }
```

Im calling this method in a timer tick event the timer1 interval is set to 1000ms
What happen now is that the progrsssBar1 move by 10's getting to 90% after 9 times it's moving back to 0 to value 0. Wht it's not getting to 100% to the end ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
 PprogressBar1.Maximum = YourMaximumValue; // like for example 1,000,000
```

and then increment by 1

```
Counter += 1;
ProgressBar1.Value = Counter;
```

Your formula in your question results in a decimal which is always less than 100 (Like 98.55).

Comment: Transcendent then again it will get to 90% and then will reset to 0 or will get to 100% and start from 10.  I want that it will start allways from 0 to 100 and then again 0 to 100.  0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100 ... 0,10,20...then if i change the checking from == 10 to == 20 then it should start from 0,20,40,60,80,100  0,20,40,60,80....and so on.

Comment: @user3781243: I don't understand what exactly you are up to, but in that case (if you have multiple processes) you can show multiple progress bars, so show progress bar y for task 1, if task completed, then update progress bar x. what you are doing as I said is not a logical way.

Comment: @user3781243: also be careful, your rounding formula never ever results in 100!

Answer (score 2):

When the counter equals 10, the progress is 100%. However, you're setting the progressBar1.Value = 0; so it never reaches 100% before the UI can update.

Comment: Michael true but the reason i added the progressBar1.Value = 0;  is that without it when it's getting to 100 it's starting again from 10. And i want it like im reseting counter to 0 also the progressBar to start over again from 0 not 10.

Comment: His rounded number also never reaches 100, there's only one case where it would be 100, because only a specific digit can result in that. so he's approach is totally wrong.